# Table Format HTML

Tags: html

Could any one give the html code for the below table using rowspan and colspan

[image]

Many Thanks
Hari Gillala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyway the answer:

```
<table border="1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td rowspan="2" colspan="3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This table is not occupying the entire space. Its just occuping little area in one corner. What to do if it has to be page width.?

Comment: You should probably also add style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" on parent elements, such as the <body> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this should be moved to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

No rowspans are necessary for that layout.

```
<table>
   <tr><td>
   <table>
      <tr><td></td></tr>
      <tr><td></td></tr>
   </table>
   </td><td>
   <table>
      <tr><td colspan="3"></td></tr>
      <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
   </table>
   </td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: why do you need nested tables for this?

Comment: Because the two horizontal lines don't line up. Both sides of the outer table only have two rows, but they are different heights. The only way rowspan might be able to handle such a situation is to split into 3 rows but offsetting rows like that is going to behave differently from browser to browser.

Comment: however two rows are visible, the html structure can contain three <tr> elements. Please have a look at the solution I posted too. I guess with that example it's not a browser issue.